# Pandas: merged data frame has more rows than the original ones

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset df with this shape (1038828, 6)

```
lib_source = df['LIB_SOURCE']
lib_source = pd.get_dummies(lib_source, prefix='source', prefix_sep='_')
```

lib_source has the same shape : (1038828, 2)

After I merge lib_source with df :

```
df = df.join(lib_source)
```

And now df shape is (1777590, 7).

Why please I don'k keep the initial shape please?
Thanks.

Comment: This means you have duplicated indices. Can you provide a reproducible sample?

Comment: Ok. No I have not reproducible sample. So a reindex of df should fix?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pd.concat` instead:

```
df = pd.concat([df, lib_source], axis=1)
```